# std::out_of_range error when comparing symbols in strings

Tags: c++, string, exception, std

I'm learning C++ and in this assignment I'm to learn about various errors regarding C++. I identified and fixed two prior errors in this code, but the third error which happens during the run-phase of the program throwing "std::out_of_range" and closing.

The program is not written by me, but it's basically hangman word guessing.
The exception occurs when the last letter is guessed correctly.

Link to the entire code is https://onlinegdb.com/Hk-84-WSz , but the relevant stuff happens at lines 100 and 106 as far as I've been able to find out.

The entire error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'                                                                                                                  
what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)                                                                                                          
Aborted
```

And here is the function causing the exception:

```
bool onko_sana_jo_arvattu(std::string sala, std::string arvatut)
{

    for (std::string::size_type indeksi = 0; indeksi <= sala.size(); ++indeksi)
    {
    // The next line seems to be causing the exception when the last letter has been guessed
        if (arvatut.find(sala.at(indeksi)) == std::string::npos)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "stuff" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
indeksi <= sala.size()
```

must be:

```
indeksi < sala.size()
```

as `std::string` is indexed from `0` to `size - 1`.

Comment: Yeah, just got the same answer from Discord. A bit flabbergasted that I'd missed even trying something like that even if I didn't "see" it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for (std::string::size_type indeksi = 0; indeksi <= sala.size(); ++indeksi)
```

changed to

```
for (std::string::size_type indeksi = 0; indeksi < sala.size(); ++indeksi)
```

Solution found from Discord ("Programming Discussion")